# maven version not recognized command

Tags: maven

using windows 10 system.

1. downloaded maven
2. In Environment variables --- I can't add to system variables no access. 
   In user variables set the `M2_HOME`, `MAVEN_HOME` both
3. To path added `%M2_HOME%;%M2_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;`
4. Opened command prompt. it's at c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32> 
   when i typed mvn -version   ---- it says not recognized command

maven is set in user variables in environment settings. what am I missing here? am I checking it right?

Comment: Did you restart the command prompt? The environment vars are set when the shell is started...

Comment: do "echo %PATH%" in your cmd and check if maven is actually added to your PATH variable or not....

Comment: Did you follow this? https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/
It should be very straight forward.

Comment: Yes restarted command prompt. I don't have access to modify System Variables  of environment variables. So, added the M2_HOME, M2 variables in User Variables of environment variables. In cmd window when I open I am at C:\WINDOWS\system32> when I did echo %PATH% I am seeing the path to maven and also maven\bin too. When I typed set M2_HOME it displayed M2_HOME=path to maven. set JAVA_HOME displayed the JDK path as well. But mvn -version getting mvn not recognized command. what am I missing? Only thing is instead of adding the variables to system variables added them to user variables

Answer (score 2):

Yo can try these :

In command prompt - Run --> set MAVEN_HOME 
to see if the user variables are setup

Try restarting command prompt and give it a try

run --> set path 
to see if the values are setup

Comment: In cmd window when I open I am at C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %PATH% I am seeing the path to maven and also maven\bin too. When I typed set M2_HOME as you suggested and it displayed M2_HOME=path to maven. set JAVA_HOME displayed the JDK path as well. But mvn -version getting mvn not recognized command. what am I missing? As mentioned I added the environment variables to User Settings not system variables as I mentioned I have no access to system variables

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have JDK installed because Maven needs JDK as a [requirement](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Requirements) and JAVA_HOME set up as follows,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3
```

and path variable contains %JAVA_HOME%

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin
```

You need to have the M2_HOME setup to the maven installed location. Usually, it is as follows.

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3
```

And then, you need to have the M2 Variable setup to point to the bin directory like follows,

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

Path variable should include the %M2%

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

Then, open up a new command prompt by running CMD in start menu. Then type for

```
mvn -version
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try reinstalling the maven setup - It could be corrupted. 
Try this - Go to maven bin folder and try to print the version . Notice that I havent setup M2_HOME or MAVEN_HOME

See below:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.3, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>java -version
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)

C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>set M2_HOME
Environment variable M2_HOME not defined

C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>set MAVEN_HOME
Environment variable MAVEN_HOME not defined

C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin>set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed all variables from my PC for debugging and tried as shown below - Maven version seem to work fine after setting M2 & MAVEN_HOME. 
You can follow the same as shown by manually setting the variables in command prompt until you can fix the automatic settings on your PC.

```
**C:\Users\000>mvn -version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

C:\Users\000>set MAVEN_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.6.3

C:\Users\000>set M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.6.3

C:\Users\000>
C:\Users\000>set PATH=C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;%PATH%

C:\Users\000>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.3, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\Users\000>java -version
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```